# Splitting a single Excel column into two separate columns, splitting the values?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

How do I split a single Excel column whose values are defined as such:

=HYPERLINK("http://whatever.com","Website Title")

into two separate columns, one with the title ("Website Title") and another with the URL ("http://whatever.com")

anyone?

(this is for Excel 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if you're willing to use VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitHyperLinkFormula()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        If InStr(1, r.Formula, "=hyperlink", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = GetHyperlink(r.Formula) 'Split URL
            r.Offset(0, 2).Value = r.Value                 'Split Title
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Function GetHyperlink(s As String)
    'Requires =HYPERLINK formula, assumes hyperlink has no commas.
    s = Left(s, InStr(s, ",") - 2)
    GetHyperlink = Right(s, Len(s) - 12)
End Function
```

Just highlight whatever you need split and run SplitHyperLinkFormula. It will put the two values you wanted in the two cells to the right of your cell.

Warning: If for some reason your hyperlink has a comma in it, this will only return the portion of the URL before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use VBA.

1. Select the range, use Find Replace to change = signs to something else (like #). This replaces formula with string like

   '#HYPERLINK("http://whatever.com","Website Title")'
2. Use Text to Columns, using " (double quote) as delimiter, and discard all columns except URL and Website Title.